# check inputted data with database in laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel

I have 3 data in the user's table.

[image: data in users table]

while login I want to check the inputted data with all in the data in the table. I tried but it's not working.

```
  $user = User::where('status',1)->where('deleted_at',null)->get();
      print_r($user); die;

    if(User::where(['type' => $user_type,'user_id' => $user_id,'email' => $email,'password' => $password ,'status'=> 1, 'deleted_at' => null])){
   // if($user_type == $type && $user_id == $uid && $email == $uemail && Hash::check($password,$upass)){

       // echo "Sucess.";die;
        Session::put('userSession',$email);
        Session::put('loginSession',$user_type);

         return view('death_notice.dashboard');

    } else {
       echo "Failed.";die;
       return redirect('/user')->with('flash_message_error','Invalid Login Credentials..');
      }
```

Please help me to find the solution...

Comment: What is the expected result, and what is the actual result. what did you mean by 'Not Working'?

Comment: its a login function which is not working..

Comment: Check my answer below. I think that was the issue.

Comment: it gives empty result.........

Answer (score 0):

for login check use

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Auth::attempt();
```

in your case try

```
if(Auth::attempt(['type' => $user_type,'user_id' => $user_id,'email' => $email,'password' => $password ,'status'=> 1, 'deleted_at' => null])){
    // success
} else {
    // error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with this.

1. In the first if statement, you are calling `->get()` on the user model, which will result in a Collection of users, rather than a single user. Use `->first()`
2. The second if statement isn't calling `->first()`, therefore the query builder is just being returned.

Laravel provides login functionality, to which you can pass additional parameters.

```
$rememberMe = false;

if (auth()->attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'additional_check' => 'something-else'], $rememberMe) {
  // user is logged in
}
```

Now i'm not certain as to why you require two if statements, they seem unrelated.

Comment: but i checks only one data which doesnot checks other users.

Answer (score 0):

there is a fault in your if condition.

To an `if` condition you must pass a `boolean` value.

But you have passed a `Query Builder` instance.

To get a boolean output from database query existence, you can call `exists()`

```
if(User::where([
    'type' => $user_type,
    'user_id' => $user_id,
    'email' => $email,
    'password' => bcrypt($password) ,
    'status'=> 1,
    'deleted_at' => null])->exists())
```

Comment: it gives empty result

Comment: `  $user = User::where('status',1)->where('deleted_at',null)->get();
      print_r($user); die;` did you remove this code?

Comment: yes..but the problem is in password where the password is in hash in database which is checking without hasing..

Comment: Oh ofcourse I didn't notice that. use  `bcrypt()` function. I updated the answer